# GetKeyDown behaving strange, Unity, C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue with the GetKeyDown in Unity. Even though the log seems to detect every time the button is pressed, it doesn't always execute the code. Seems to happen more when taping the button rapidly. What I want is to decrease "counting" until zero and then after x seconds refill to its initial value.

```
int counting = 5;

void Update(){

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O) && counting > 0){
        counting --;
    }
    else if(counting <= 0)
    {
        Invoke ("ResetCounting",3);
    }

    print (counting);
}

void ResetCounting ()
{
    counting = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep tapping the key while `counting` is already `0`, you will trigger `ResetCounting()` several times. When `counting` gets reset to `5` there are still some calls to `ResetCounting()` in the queue and will reset `counting` while it still is greater than `0`.

You need to add a check that ensures that `ResetCounting()` is only triggered once.

```
int counting = 5;
bool invokedReset = false;

void Update(){

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O) && counting > 0){
        counting --;
    }
    else if(counting <= 0 && !invokedReset)
    {
        Invoke ("ResetCounting",3);
        invokedReset = true;
    }

    print (counting);
}

void ResetCounting ()
{
    counting = 5;
    invokedReset = false;
}
```

Comment: Of course, makes so much sense now when you say it. Thank you!